# How to concatenate multiple Python dictionaries to return as one dictionary from multiple member functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a Flask endpoint that calls a Python class and passes a userid to the Python class.  After the lookup of the ID, then multiple other member methods would be called (either as making them helpers like `self.anothermethod()` or similar.

So for example, using the ID, I look up 5 different datasets by calling 5 member methods each of them returning a unique dictionary.

the question is how would be an elegant way to combine each dictionary as it returns and then just return the 1 large complete dictionary from all the calls to Flask.

Comment: For each method, have a separate key that indicates the value from that method

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge two dictionaries with the `update()` method

```
>>> a = {"key1": "value1"}
>>> b = {"key2": "value2"}
>>> a.update(b)
>>> a
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

So in your example, you could start with an empty dictionary and update as you go

```
d = {}
d.update(method1())
d.update(method2())
...
return d
```

Comment: Thank you!  Much appreciated